# Recyclerview not refreshing after removing an item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Recycler view is not updating after an item is removed.
This recyclerView is inside a fragment.
I have tried every method and nothing works.

> Adapter declaration in fragment class

```
    notificationsTabAdapter = new NotificationsTabAdapter(getContext(), R.id.notificationsRecyclerView,
                notificationItemsList, cListner);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationsTabAdapter);
```

> RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class NotificationsTabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsTabAdapter.NotificationItemHolder> {

Boolean debug = false;
public static final String NOTIFICATION_ADAPTER = "NotificationAdapter";
private ArrayList<NotificationItemm> notificationItems;
private int layoutResID;
private int notificationposition;
private Context myContext;
public onNotificationItemClickListner mListner;


public interface onNotificationItemClickListner {
    void onNotificationItemDelete(int position);
}

public NotificationsTabAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationItemm> notificationList,
                               onNotificationItemClickListner listner) {
    myContext = context;
    layoutResID = resource;
    notificationItems = notificationList;
    notificationposition = 0;
    this.mListner = listner;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NotificationItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notifications_tab_item, viewGroup, false);
    NotificationsTabAdapter.NotificationItemHolder evh = new NotificationsTabAdapter.NotificationItemHolder(view, mListner);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotificationItemHolder notificationItemHolder, final int position) {

    final NotificationItemm currentItem = notificationItems.get(position);

    notificationItemHolder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotification_name());
    notificationItemHolder.mNotificationURL = currentItem.getNotification_link();
    notificationItemHolder.mNotificationDate = currentItem.getNotification_date();
    notificationItemHolder.mNotificationRT = currentItem.getNotification_rT();

    notificationItemHolder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    //to delete the notification
    notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteNotification(currentItem);

            mListner.onNotificationItemDelete(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notificationItems.size();
}

//Delete from View

public void deleteNotification(NotificationItemm todelete) {
    int notificationPosition = notificationItems.indexOf(todelete);
    notificationItems.remove(notificationPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(notificationPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(notificationPosition);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemRemoved(notificationPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(notificationPosition);

    if (notificationItems.isEmpty()) {

    }
}

/**
 * VIEW HOLDER =================================================================================
 **/

public class NotificationItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout mNotificaionHolderLayout;
    RelativeLayout notificationParentRelative;
    ImageView imageDelete;
    TextView mNotificationTextView;
    String mNotificationURL;
    String mNotificationDate;
    String mNotificationRT;

    public NotificationItemHolder(@NonNull View itemView, onNotificationItemClickListner listner) {

        super(itemView);
        mNotificationTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationTextView);
        mNotificaionHolderLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification__item_container);
        imageDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_delete_image);
        notificationParentRelative = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlNotificLayout);
        mNotificationRT = null;
        mNotificationURL = null;
        mNotificationDate = null;
    }
}
```

}

When I debug the project, I can see that the item is actually removing from the ArrayList.But not updating in recycled view.

**After deletion, if the recyclerview is scrolled, the deleted item is removed from the recyclerview.But not without scrolling.**

Comment: yes even i had the same problem

Comment: @bk7 did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yes i did after some research

Comment: share your NotificationsTabAdapter constructor code i will post the solution

Comment: I think you have to set notifydatasetchanged() in your fragment with callback and set adapter to your recyclerview again.

Comment: Please post your  constructor of adapter

Comment: That may be because of Adapter constructor parameters

Comment: I have added the constructor code,please check

Comment: i have added the answer please check @Lenzman

Comment: On Delete notification clicked paste to `deleteNotification` clicked position of an item as an argument. Then remove item using position from notificationItemsList and notify. Next time upload full code. Don't waste others time.

Comment: try adding this `notificationsTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in after `setAdapter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **NotificationsTabAdapter** make the following changes

```
   NotificationsTabAdapterListener notificationsTabAdapterListener;

   public interface NotificationsTabAdapterListener { // create an interface
        void onItemsDeleted(int position); // create callback function
    }

public NotificationsTabAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationItemm> notificationList,
                           NotificationsTabAdapterListener notificationsTabAdapterListener) {
myContext = context;
layoutResID = resource;
notificationItems = notificationList;
notificationposition = 0;
this.notificationsTabAdapterListener = notificationsTabAdapterListener;
```

}

```
      notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//perform normal remove operation here

notificationItems.remove(position);
            notificationsTabAdapterListener.onItemsDeleted(position);
        }
    });
```

And Implement **NotificationsTabAdapterListener** in you fragment  and in override method  use the following code

```
        @Override
public void onItemsDeleted(final int position) {
    notificationsTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did, and now I am getting a null point Exception on onNotificationItemDelete callback in the interface

Comment: did you implement NotificationsTabAdapterListener in your fragment?

Comment: and passed it in NotificationsTabAdapter constructor

Comment: Yes I have,but still

Comment: change from  yourAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged(); to notificationsTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   in onNotificationItemDelete callback

Comment: i have already added notificationsTabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to the calback

Comment: notificationsTabAdapter = new NotificationsTabAdapter(getContext(), R.id.notificationsRecyclerView,
                notificationItemsList, this);   -- are you creating your adapter like this?

Comment: no. I have already added the code of fragment class where the adapter is created.

Comment: yes you are passing **cListner** instead of **this**

Comment: Yup, Yes,...Got it

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Hope will work for you.

```
notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           notificationItems.remove(position);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Might be issue with item object (it may be referring different one). Can you post your full adapter class? so we  may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your delete functionality

```
public void deleteNotification(NotificationItemm todelete) {
    notificationItems.remove(todelete);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: No,this works as same as i have written,removing from dataList but recyclerview is not refreshing

Comment: Just tell me How have passed list to the recycleView adapter

Comment: notificationsTabAdapter = new NotificationsTabAdapter(getContext(), R.id.notificationsRecyclerView,
                notificationItemsList, cListner); onthis line what is type of notificationItemsList and how you have added data in list please share

Comment: Try this in the Actvity/Fragment code not in the RecyclerView Adapter code.
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: notificationItemsList  is an ArrayList of objects of another class NotificationItemm.

Comment: @AkashSureshDandwate I have added the code of my construstor in the post

Comment: am saying that how you have addded this data to list

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can call a method in the FragmentClass, which loads the new list (with item removed) in your adapter. Call this method from your Adapter

```
public void MethodInFragmentClass(NotificationItemm todelete)
{
/*
... delete item 
*/
notificationsTabAdapter = new NotificationsTabAdapter(getContext(), R.id.notificationsRecyclerView,
                notificationDeletedItemsList, cListner);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationsTabAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use a callback like this in your adapter :**

```
private ICallback mICallback;

    public interface ICallback {

      void deleteItem(int position);
    }
    public SettingRecyclerViewAdapter(SettingMediator settingMediator, ICallback ICallback) {
        mICallback = ICallback;
        mSettingMediator = settingMediator;
    }
```

**And in your faragment notifydatasetchange and update recyclerview like this :**

```
public class YourFragment implements SettingContract.View, SettingRecyclerViewAdapter.ICallback {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void deleteItem(int position) {

                //delete item from your list here
        mSettingRecyclerViewAdapter = new SettingRecyclerViewAdapter(yourList, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSettingRecyclerViewAdapter);
        mSettingRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setTag(holder);
    notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationItemHolder viewholder = (NotificationItemHolder) v.getTag();
            notificationItems.remove(viewholder.getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the position which is getting from onclick listener in Adapter class to Interface method(onitemClicked())
Then, Implement the interface class to Fragment class and will remove the position which we have on Interface method using [ listname.remove(position)) ]
Eventually, update recyclerview UI using adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();

Step 1 :create interface class

```
public interface RecyclerviewItemClickListener {


    void onitemClicked(View v, int position);
}
```

Step 2: pass position to the interface method in adapter class

```
notificationItemHolder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        deleteNotification(currentItem);
        //use interface method & pass the position of the list to fragment for update UI .
        recyclerviewItemClickListener.onitemClicked(v,position);
    }
});
```

step 3 : implement the interface class & method in fragment

```
@Override
    public void onitemClicked(View v, int position) {

        Listname.remove(Listname.get(position));
        RecyclerviewAdaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```